# Matrices VBA Subindice fuera del intervalo

Tags: vba, matrices

Tengo un problema, a ver si me podéis ayudar.

Tengo varios archivos xml, que voy tratando uno por uno. Cojo el primero lo trato y me quedo con su información y cuando termino de recorrerlo paso al siguiente, y así hasta que ya no me queden mas archivos por tratar.

El problema es que cuando intento redimensionar la matriz, no me deja, ya que me da un erro de subíndice fuera del intervalo. No se como hacer para que la matriz vaya incrementándose cada vez que trato un nuevo fichero, eso sí manteniendo la información. Les detallo lo que tengo:

La variable Matriz () as Variant. La tengo declarada de esta forma.

```
While MyFile <> ""
    Workbooks("Fichero.xlsm").Activate
    XMLFileName = Mydir & MyFile
    Oxmlfile.Load (XMLFileName) 
    Set nodes = Oxmlfile.SelectNodes("//AINVOICELIST/*")
    aux_node = nodes.Length  'Longitud del nodo
    n = n + aux_node
    j = 1
    ReDim Preserve Matriz(n, 30)
    n = 0
    For Each node1 In nodes         
      y = 0
      Matriz(n, y) = node1.SelectSingleNode("SC").nodeTypedValue()
      Matriz(n, y + 1) = Fact & node1.SelectSingleNode("I").nodeTypedValue()
      Matriz(n, y + 2) = node1.SelectSingleNode("DATE").nodeTypedValue()
      n = n + 1
    Next
```

Posteriormente llamo a una `function` que se encarga de llevarme el fichero tratado a otra carpeta y empezar con el siguiente.

```
Traslado_fichero (MyFile)
MyFile = Dir(Path & MyExtension)
```

Cuando empiezo a tratar el Segundo fichero e intento redimensionar la matriz, es cuando ya me salta el error. Justo aquí `ReDim Preserve Matriz(n, 30)`, me muestra el mensaje "Subindice fuera del intervalo"

Podéis ayudarme por favor. Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Estimado, tengo una solución bastante fuera de los principios de programación, pero coloco un contador declarado fuera del while y al momento de salir realizo un `Array.resize(mimatriz, contador)` donde contador puede ser cualquier entero para medir una matriz bi-dimensional(en mi caso), pruebalo y me cuentas como te va.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es la variable `Matriz` es una matriz multidimensional, de hecho, bidimensional, y ReDim sólo redimensiona la última de las dimensiones.

Considerando que se trata de una matriz bidimensional, una posible solución es redimensionar una dimension y luego transponer la matriz para redimensionar la otra y luego volver a transponer para volver a la forma original. Esto tiene implicaciones en el desempeño, así que si resultara que se alenta mucho tu programa, deberías repensar acerca de si el uso de una matriz multidimensional es la estructura adecuada para lo que quieres lograr.

Pregunta similar en inglés

[ReDim Preserve to a Multi-Dimensional Array in Visual Basic 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16369217/1595451)